# How to filter the logcat using the GUI to show multiple filters?[Android Studio]

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I want to show all the log cat that I wrote in my code

I have several activities , and every one has a different tag.

In the **logcat** I just want to show these logs I wrote in my code in these specific activities .

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check "Regex" checkbox in logcat window and than use "tag1|tag2" as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Log Cat Filters for each activity

```
Android Monitor -> Edit Filter Configuration (select from right top dropdown)
```

enter your tag in Log Tag and press Ok
Then you can select any filter to debug as needed.